# cant get custom data attributes value in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

`<input type="submit" value="+" data-commentId="{{ $comment->id }}"     data-postId="{{ $post->id }}" data-likes="{{ $comment->likes }}" class="likebtn increment">`
my jquery like

```
$('.likebtn').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// commentIdとpostIdもHTMLから取ってくる
commentId = parseInt($('this').attr('data-commentId'));
console.log(commentId);
postId = parseInt($('this').attr('data-postId'));
console.log(postId);
likes = parseInt($('this').attr('data-likes'));
console.log(data-likes);
like_function(commentId, postId, likes, $('this')); });
```

In console I see these variables returns NaN.
What is wrong?

Comment: You want `$(this)` instead of `$('this')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use quotations around this.

`$(this)` Notice no quotations.